# Select Case Statement Not Working When fetching data from sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Pardon me asking, I'm stuck where my if else and select case statement will only go to ELSE option. Below is my code

```
lblStudentName.Text = CStr(studentInfo.stuFullName)
lblStudentBirthCert.Text = CStr(studentInfo.birthCert)

Dim conn As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

conn.ConnectionString = ("server = A-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=studentManagement;integrated security=true")
conn.Open()

cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblStudentBirthCert.Text)
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT paymentType From payment Where birthcert=@id")

Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim tempPaymentType As String

While reader.Read()
    Dim tempPaymentType = reader.GetString(0)
    Select Case tempPaymentType
        Case "a"
            txtFeeA.Text = tempPaymentType
        Case "b"
            txtFeeB.Text = tempPaymentType
        Case "c"
            txtFeeC.Text = tempPaymentType
        Case "d"
            txtFeeD.Text = tempPaymentType
        Case "e"
            txtFeeE.Text = tempPaymentType
        Case Else
            txtFeeF.Text = tempPaymentType
    End Select
End While
reader.Close()
```

For some reason, it will only go to else and print it out inside txtFeeF.text. The query will return 6 result btw, a to f.
It is the same with if else statement.
Without any if else and select statement, the the output will be f, which is the last in the reader.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
If tempPaymentType.Equals("a") Then
            txtFeeA.Text = tempPaymentType.ToString
        End If
```

Comment: Try Adding    Trim().ToLower()  after your GetString(0) to see if there are case issue or extra spaces

Comment: Thanks, your method works, it seems like the database add spaces in it. after the trimming, it works now. Though im not sure how to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: @SalehinSuhaimi - You can't mark comments as an answer.  You can ask Sparky to post his comment as an answer, which you can then accept.  As to why there are extra spaces, could be a number of reasons.  The column being a CHAR(2) or larger comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Adding

```
Trim().ToLower()
```

after your

```
GetString(0)
```

to see if there are case issue or extra spaces.   If the database field is a character field, it will add extra spaces, but if VARCHAR(), it should trim it..

Comment: Nitpick: `varchar` doesn't trim, it just doesn't *add* spaces. If you set it to `a ` explicitly, you will have `a `, not `a`. It's just that `a` will always be saved as `a ` into a `char(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a line to help you debug:

```
    Dim tempPaymentType = reader.GetString(0)
    Debug.Print (String.Format("tempPaymentType: {0}", tempPaymentType))
    Select Case tempPaymentType
```

There could be a lot of reasons, but you haven't given enough information. For example are the letters different cases? ("a" vs. "A")

It may help to change this code:

```
Dim tempPaymentType As String

While reader.Read()
    tempPaymentType = reader.GetString(0)
```

I'm surprised it even builds with the extra `Dim` statement.

Comment: Yeah. Just debug this! Find out what the value is and why it is wrong.

Comment: tempPaymentType: a         
tempPaymentType: b this is what i got, and a - f will always be in small letter, as this is not an optional choice, it's fixed in the database.

Comment: Have you tried removing `Dim` from this code `tempPaymentType = reader.GetString(0)` ?